# Shrink (scale) an SVG image via command line, while preserving its size

Tags: command-line, script, svg

How can I shrink the content within an SVG file from the command line? I'd like the output to have the same default width and height, but be smaller. I'd also like for the scaling to be relative to the ***centre***. Consider star.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="304" height="290">
  <path d="M2,111h300 l-242.7,176.3 92.7-285.3 92.7,285.3z"/>
</svg>
```

I'm looking for a smaller star than the one shown below; yet still in the centre of the (say: 304,290) image.

[image]